# Is it possible to read a .py (python source code) as a file and display its class name, class methods and variables as output....?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, methods

Is it possible to read a .py (python source code) as a file and display its class names, class methods and variables as output?
ps: code has to be in python itself.

Comment: Could you post some examples?

Comment: Why read it *"as a file"*? Why not just `import` it then use e.g. [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do way better.

Instead of parsing the input file as a text file simply import the python module and then call the [dir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) python built in function.

As an example: to list what you have in the os module you can do:

```
import os
dir(os)
```